# Python, printing things a select number of times

Tags: python, date

I'm new to coding and am having an issue with my program. I have to get sales information from a file and print it in a certain format. This is the code:

```
#Looping program to read file per line
for line in lines:
    # Formatting line to read later
    line = line.strip().split(',')
    year = line[0]
    year = int(year)
    month = line[1]
    month = int(month)
    day = line[2]
    day = int(day)
    linePoint = date(year, month, day)

    cost = line[3]
    cost = float(cost)

    #Finding the lines within the start and end date
    if (linePoint >= startDate) and (linePoint <= endDate):
        printcost = (cost / 100)
        printcost = int(printcost)

        print "%s.%s.%s" % (startYear, startMonth, startDay)
        print "0%s:" % printNum,  "*" * printcost

        newcost = newcost + cost
        printNum += 1
```

When I use the `%s.%s.%s` it's printing the date above the sales, I want it to print that above the other print statement once per month, and be able to increase it once the month is up.
Also in the `print "0%s:" % printNum,  "*" * printcost` statement I would like it to only print the zero for the first nine days.

Essentially my question is how in Python do I run something a certain number of times, but the number of times is dependent on the user and correlate with the date, and in order to do that the computer needs to be able to recognize the date. Sorry for the vagueness.

Comment: Show sample input and a desired output.

Comment: It seems that your code indentation may have been messed up when submitting the question. Could you check that and correct if necessary.

Comment: is `printNum` created/initialized before the code you show? It's printed it with a string format, but then incremented like a number. FWIW, if you want to print an int with leading 0s, you could do `print '%02d' % printNum'

Comment: need examples of startDate and endDate. Also need date function

Answer (score 1):

If you want the output to be `'01', '02', ..., '10', '11', ...` then the format you want to use is:

```
print "%02d" % printNum
```

As for printing the header out at the start of each new month (that's how I'm reading the first part of your question, you could do something like:

```
old_month = 0
for line in lines:
    # do stuff
    month = whatever...
    if month != old_month:
        # print header here
        old_month = month
    #rest of loop
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost sure this is what you want. Note the "%02d" [format specifier](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language), which gives you the leading zero, and the check to see if the month has changed via `if month != current_month`.

```
current_month, print_num, new_cost = None, 0, 0

for line in lines:
    fields = line.strip().split(',')
    year = int(fields[0])
    month = int(fields[1])
    day = int(fields[2])
    cost = float(fields[3])

    line_date = date(year, month, day)

    #Finding the lines within the start and end date
    if startDate <= line_date <= endDate:
        if month != current_month:
            print "%s.%s.%s" % (year, month, day)
            current_month = month

        print_cost = int(cost / 100)
        print "%02d: %s" % (print_num,  "*" * print_cost)

        new_cost += cost
        print_num += 1
```